# Naming conventions in GMP documentation

Tags: c++, gmp

Currently I am looking at the GMP library's documentation, and I am having some difficulty understanding the naming conventions of the variables listed in the function specifications.

Particularly the use of `rop` and `op` confuses me.

Here is the page that lists import and export functions, and due to my confusion with the naming conventions, I am having a lot of trouble understanding exactly what they are to do.

https://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Import-and-Export.html

Would it be possible to get an explanation on the naming conventions of the variables, and an explanation of what the functions do (in hopes that I can get an even better understanding that just knowing the naming conventions could provide)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The naming conventations of GMP library are that `rop` means an *result operand* or *output operand*. while `op` is an *input operand*. Notice, that you may have multiple `rop`s per one function in this manner.

The GMP's API functions are designed, so that `rop`s are always placed *before* `op`s. Regarding to its documentation, [§3.4 *Variable Conventions*](https://gmplib.org/manual/Variable-Conventions.html#Variable-Conventions):

> GMP functions generally have output arguments before input arguments.
>   This notation is by analogy with the assignment operator.

For instance, to compute square root of big integer, you would function declared with prototype as:

```
void mpz_sqrt (mpz t rop, const mpz t op);
```

where the `rop` stores result of `sqrt(op)`.